How to combine batch files
I have 4 batch files I run for MKV files. The first renames all the files, the second removes any comments in all the files, the 3rd edits the "Title" in the metadata to match the filenames and the 4th creates a directory of each filename, then moves the mkvs into them.
All 4 files work perfectly but I'm trying to combine them into a single batch file. I've managed to do it, and it's not pretty, but it works. The problem is, when all the files are done, gone through all of the processes, the batch file won't end. It keeps restarting over and over.
Here is the combined batchfile...
@ECHO OFF
@echo Renaming Files...
pause
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "mkv=C:\Users\Immortalis\Downloads\-=UT=-\! SAVED DOWNLOADS\mkvtoolnix\mkvpropedit.exe"
pushd "."
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s /o-n') DO (
   SET "_FFN=%%~fG"                                    File Full Name
   SET "Var=%%~nxG"                                    File Name + Extension
   call :renaming
)
popd
ENDLOCAL
goto :EOF

:renaming
   SET "Var=%Var:(1={1%"
   SET "Var=%Var:(2={2%"
   SET "Var=%Var:0)=0}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:1)=1}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:2)=2}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:3)=3}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:4)=4}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:5)=5}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:6)=6}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:7)=7}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:8)=8}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:9)=9}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:(Ur)=(U)%"
   SET "Var=%Var:(Unrated)=(U)%"
   SET "Var=%Var:.trim01=%"
   SET "Var=%Var:[DR]=[D]%"
   SET "Var=%Var:[WR]=[W]%"
   SET "Var=%Var:[HD]=[H]%"
   SET "Var=%Var:[BR]=[B]%"
   SET "Var=%Var:[s={s%"
   SET "Var=%Var:00]=00}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:01]=01}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:02]=02}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:03]=03}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:04]=04}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:05]=05}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:06]=06}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:07]=07}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:08]=08}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:09]=09}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:10]=10}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:11]=11}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:12]=12}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:13]=13}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:14]=14}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:15]=15}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:16]=16}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:17]=17}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:18]=18}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:19]=19}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:20]=20}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:21]=21}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:22]=22}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:23]=23}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:24]=24}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:25]=25}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:26]=26}%"
rename "%_FFN%" "%Var%"
@echo Removing Comments...
pause
for /R "." %%I in (*.mkv) do "%mkv%" "%%I" --tags all: -d title --delete-attachment 1
@echo Setting Title to filename...
pause
for /R "." %%I in (*.mkv) do "%mkv%" "%%I" --edit info --set title="%%~nI"
@echo Placing files in separate directories...
pause
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
goto :EOF

:EOF
@echo Processes Complete!
pause


Why didn't you just create a fifth batch file that does nothing but call the other four: It would have been much easier, and you'd still only be running one file. Also, you're going to need to be more specific. How far is it getting in the process before the issue occurs? You;'re outputting status information to the terminal, so you should be able to narrow down the area of the code that is having issues. I don't see anything obvious that would make it call itself recursively. Have you tried commenting out parts of the code in order to be able to track it down?

The 5th batch file makes sense... I'll give that a try. As for how far it's getting,  I mentioned, it completes everything right to the end, but then it starts over and keeps looping.

Actually, the only place that could cause recursion is call :renaming. It looks like maybe it's not exiting that loop.

The fifth batch file solution would be easy. The fifth file could be called something like Cleanup.bat. It would have four lines, each containing the name of one of the other four, each on its own line. Something like RenameFiles, CleanComments, ChangeTitles, MoveTheFiles.

After renaming, it exits the loop and  does all the other processes, but then it goes back to renaming and goes through all the processes again, over and over

I tried the 5th batch file idea and it didn't rename the file, therefore it edit the title with the wrong name, created a directory with the wrong name and moved the file into it.

Then your four separate batch files couldn't have been working perfectly, could they?

I can't explain it... but running them individually, they work just fine. Does exactly what I need it to do.

Ok, I got the 5th batch file idea working. The problem had to with the filename of the test file. Once I fixed that, then the batch file renames it properly ten completes the other processes.

Having it all in 1 file would have been more convenient, but things are still better than they were. Thank you all for your help.

I think this line is wrong or incomplete: if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (. There is not any matching previous for %%i ... command

I'm not sure what you mean, but that's from the 4th batch file which works fine and I've never had any issues with it. I didn't create any of these batch files, they were found on the net and I've modified them for my own use so if there's something wrong, I wouldn't know what or how to remedy it... which is why I'm here :)

The comment by @Aacini does not state it will not work, he said it is wrong, i.e it will not process that if statement. You have never set %%i only %%I

If :renaming is meant as a subroutine, there is an exit /b missing. For an example of the syntax, look here. Also, make sure that the "flow" does not run into your subroutine - you can achieve that with a goto which is placed before the label.

In your 4th batch file, before the if not "%%~ni" == "organize" ( line, it must be a for %%i ... line that you missed in the combined batch file. Check it! Anyway, your whole logic is wrong. See my answer below...

If you want to combine your batch files into one you can use this structure (let's assume you have PartOne.cmd, PartTwo.cmd, PartThree.cmd, PartFour.cmd as separate files):
File AllParts.cmd:
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo Start processing...

REM Here is a good place for parameters used by all parts - Store them
REM in environment variables to be used across the parts

call :PartOne
call :PartTwo
call :PartThree
call :PartFour
goto :Done

:PartOne
REM ... your code of PartOne.cmd ...
exit /b

:PartTwo
REM ... your code of PartTwo.cmd  ...
exit /b

:PartThree
REM ... your code of PartThree.cmd  ...
exit /b

:PartFour
REM ... your code of PartFour.cmd  ...
exit /b

:Error
ECHO Error occurred: %errormsg%. Exiting with code 1 ...
ENDLOCAL
EXIT 1

:Done
ENDLOCAL
ECHO Processing done!
EXIT 0

Copy the parts of your cmd files into this single file and test it. Essentially this converts each file into a subroutine which resides now in the new file AllParts.cmd. Each subroutine is then called in sequential order (e.g. call :PartOne).
Note:

The command exit /b makes sure that the code continues at the line following the call statement. Just using exit would end the batch file (which you don't want).
In the call command it is important to use the colon (:), without it call would look for an external command being available in the path and execute it, for example call calc.exe will open the Windows calculator.
It could be that you have conflicting command line parameters (i.e. you are using them in the various parts differently). Consolidate them and store them in environment variables at the top of your call chain. This might require some refactoring.
[Optional] If you want, you can end the application with exit 0 - this allows you to flag successful termination. In case of early exit (because of an error), you can use exit 1 which allows you to call the batch from another file or run a command and then check against errorlevel 1. The condition errorlevel 1 is true, if the last command has set any exit code above 0 (typically if it aborted abnormally with an error). You can then jump there via (for example)set errormsg=Cannot copy file somefile.txtcopy C:\tmp\somefile.txt C:\Users\myUser\Documents\if errorlevel 1 goto :Error.
[Optional] If you want to auto-elevate your script, here is how you can do that.


That works beautifully!!! Thank you so much!!

Glad to hear that! :-)

The four original batch files process all *.mkv files each. In your combined batch file, for each .mkv file that the original first batch file process with FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s /o-n') DO ( command, you call the other three files! This means that 2nd, 3rd and 4th batch files are called many times!
I GUESS that your combined batch file should look like this:
@ECHO OFF
@echo Renaming Files...
pause
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "mkv=C:\Users\Immortalis\Downloads\-=UT=-\! SAVED DOWNLOADS\mkvtoolnix\mkvpropedit.exe"
REM  pushd "."  <- this command is not useful
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s /o-n') DO (
   SET "_FFN=%%~fG"                                & REM    File Full Name
   SET "Var=%%~nxG"                                & REM    File Name + Extension
   call :renaming
)
REM  popd   <- the same

@echo Removing Comments...
pause
for /R "." %%I in (*.mkv) do "%mkv%" "%%I" --tags all: -d title --delete-attachment 1
@echo Setting Title to filename...
pause
for /R "." %%I in (*.mkv) do "%mkv%" "%%I" --edit info --set title="%%~nI"
@echo Placing files in separate directories...
pause
FOR something %%i ... (     <- this command was missed from the original 4th batch file!
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)

@echo Processes Complete!
pause
ENDLOCAL
goto :EOF

:renaming
   SET "Var=%Var:(1={1%"
   SET "Var=%Var:(2={2%"
   SET "Var=%Var:0)=0}%"

   . . . the rest of renaming lines

   SET "Var=%Var:25]=25}%"
   SET "Var=%Var:26]=26}%"
rename "%_FFN%" "%Var%"
goto :EOF

Perhaps you would also like to short the :renaming subroutine this way:
:renaming
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

   for %%i in (1 2) SET "Var=!Var:(%%i={%%i!"
   for /L %%i in (0,1,9) do SET "Var=!Var:%%i)=%%i}!"  &  SET "Var=!Var:0%%i]=0%%i}!"
   for %%a in ("(Ur)=(U)" "(Unrated)=(U)" ".trim01=" "[DR]=[D]" "[WR]=[W]" "[HD]=[H]" "[BR]=[B]" "[s={s" do (
      SET "Var=!Var:%%~a!"
   )
   for /L %%i in (10,1,26) do SET "Var=!Var:%%i]=%%i}!"

rename "!_FFN!" "!Var!"
goto :EOF

PS - You should not define a :EOF label. Such a label is ignored. The goto :EOF command always terminate the batch file or subroutine...

As mentioned... somewhere in one of these comments, I didn't create these scripts, I found them on the net and modified them for my own use. Things that are wrong, missing or irrelevant, is beyond me. They were all working just fine, I just wanted to make it easier by combining them into 1 batch file which Matt has thankfully accomplished.

This is funny! Two or three times you said you prefer to combine your 4 batch files in just one. I provided you with the correct code that do that, and you rejected it! Did you tested it at least? You combined the 4 batch files in one, so I suppose you could check if you missed one line from the 4th batch file. Isn't it?

Aacini, Yes, you are right. I did miss that line somehow. You had mentioned it and I didn't give it much merit because with each of the batch files, I simply did CTRL-A CTRL-C CTRL-V so missing a line isn't possible and since the batch files work individually, shouldn't need that line (even if it was proper). I just looked at the original batch files and saw that I did indeed miss that line. I'm oblivious to explain how that's possible, but I did miss it. I haven't tested your suggestion, but most likely that would have solved the problem. I sincerely apologize.

Actually, in thinking about it a bit more. I think after copy/paste all into one batch file, I think I purposefully removed that line thinking it wouldn't matter because that parameter is already defined earlier on. All the same, again, I apologize.
